# Convolving with the frequency response of a filter

Tags: filters, fourier-transform

With `scipy` I can use `signal.butter` and `signal.lfilter` on a time signal.
Performing a Fourier transform then shows me that the filter worked.

Using `signal.freqz` I can get the frequency response of the filter. Is there anything stopping me from simply taking the FT of my time signal and convolving it with my frequency response?

Comment: Nothing stops you. BTW, if you convolving in frequency is like multiplying in time.

Comment: Note that multiplying two FFTs results in the same as a **circular** convolution in the time domain.  So be prepared for the beginning and/or end of your "filtered" time domain signal block to look funny.